# How to consume Dialogflow small talk APIs in a HTML5 app?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, dialogflow-es

I have a chat bot that is deployed in SAP Cloud Platform which answers using an NLP.
I want to integrate Dialogflow small talk with it using APIs.

I have created a project in Dialogflow and able to use small talk. However, I need APIs to call this small talk in a HTML5 applicaiton.
Is it possible to use small talk using APIs or is it only available with Dialogflow and if APIs are available, How to consume them?

I have tried dialogflow.projects.getAgent in Google API Explorer which gives me response but in postman I am getting following error as I am unable to generate API  Key:

Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have two questions:

1. How do you properly authenticate a Dialogflow v2 API request

there are two versions of Dialogflow's API: v1 and the v2 beta. 
 You might consider using [the v1 API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/) if you're having trouble using the v2 API as it uses much simpler client and developer access tokens.  If you'd like to use v2 though, see [Dialogflow's v2 authentication guide](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v2-auth-setup).

2. is there a way to get a Dialogflow agent's response via an API call

there is an API to query a Dialogflow agent and get a response back. In Dialogflow's v2 API its called [detectIntent](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent) and for v1 its called [query](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query)